# How can you efficiently identify sales patterns using R?

Tags: r, dplyr

*Please Note: The following scenario and dataset are made up for purposes of example; however, any learnings here can be applied to the task I am trying to accomplish, or similar tasks that others would like to accomplish:*

**The Goal:** Using monthly sales data, identify the point of shift (month and year) when a customer shifts from purchasing product X to product Y.

**The Challenge:** Finding/Creating a function that identifies a customers buying pattern and outputs the following information:

- Time of Shift (Month/Year)
- Sales Volume ($) Shifted
- The **Product Shifted From** & **Product Shifted To** in final data set (Final data set should have one line per customer and should contain this information on row...I cannot currently figure out how to do that).

**Additional Notes:**

- Each customer may be buying a handful of products (X, Y, Z, etc.), but each customer has a primary product that they purchase the most of - I'm looking specifically for the shift of a customers primary product. That means first identifying the primary product, then identifying if/when a shift has occurred to another primary product.
- The shift for a customer is not necessarily instant - It can take 3 or 4 months for the shift to become evident. In other words, they might start buying Product Y while Product X is still their primary product, but after a couple of months, the purchases of product Y outweigh the purchases of Product X. Ideally, I would be able to flag if it appears shift is occurring and then flag the shift based on some sort of adjustable variable (perhaps XX% of total purchase volume).

**My Current Work:**
To date, I have developed a program that is able to flag the customers shift from purchasing product X to Product Y. However, this is being done using annual purchasing volume rather than monthly. As a result of this, the shift is identified too late and the time of shift (month, year) is hard to pinpoint.

Below is step by step of what I have developed thus far using the attached data set [.csv format]:
*(The only package I have used is dplyr)*

**Sample Data:** https://github.com/timdagostino/shift_analysis

1. Remove Unique Rows: If a customer is purchasing only one product, there can be no shift and can be removed.

```
purchases_without_unique <- subset(raw_data,duplicated(Customer.ID) | duplicated(Customer.ID, fromLast=TRUE))
```

2. Reorder Data Frame Columns (personal preference)

```
purchases_reordered <- purchases_without_unique[,c(1:3, 4:ncol(purchases_without_unique))]
purchases_reordered_final <- purchases_reordered[,c(1:3, ncol(purchases_reordered):4)]
```

3. Create Sales Total for Each Year

```
purchases_reordered_final$sum_18 <- rowSums(purchases_reordered_final[,4:15])
purchases_reordered_final$sum_19 <- rowSums(purchases_reordered_final[,16:27])
purchases_reordered_final$sum_20 <- rowSums(purchases_reordered_final[,28:37])
```

4. Aggregate total sales volume by Customer

```
purchases_reordered_summary <- purchases_reordered_final %>%
  group_by(Customer.ID) %>%
  summarise(agg_18 = sum(sum_18), agg_19 = sum(sum_19), agg_20 = sum(sum_20))
```

5. Join aggregated sales to table with customer data

```
combined <- left_join(purchases_reordered_final, purchases_reordered_summary, by = "Customer.ID")
```

6. Establish a **Shift Indicator** (i.e. the percentage of total sales that must switch over to a specific product in order to be considered a "shift") and **Minimum Total Sales volume** (i.e. I don't care about small customers).

```
sh <- 1
minimum <- 100
```

7. Calculate % of Total Sales by Year & The Annual Deltas: This helps to identify in what year the shift from purchasing Product X to product Y occurred, *but ideally I would be able to pinpoint a specific month.*

```
combined_final <- combined %>%
  mutate(Percent_of_Total_18 = round(sum_18/agg_18, digits = 3)) %>%
  mutate(Percent_of_Total_19 = round(sum_19/agg_19, digits = 3)) %>%
  mutate(Percent_of_Total_20 = round(sum_20/agg_20, digits = 3)) %>%
  mutate(Annual_Delta_18_19 = Percent_of_Total_19 - Percent_of_Total_18) %>%
  mutate(Annual_Delta_19_20 = Percent_of_Total_20 - Percent_of_Total_19)
```

8. Run ifelse logic statements to flag customers experienceing shift based, identify the year time frame it is happening in, and the "to" and "from" product shifts.

```
final_results <- combined_final %>%
  mutate(Shift_Flag = ifelse(Annual_Delta_18_19 < -sh | Annual_Delta_19_20 < -sh | Annual_Delta_18_19 > sh | Annual_Delta_19_20 > sh, "Shift", "No Shift")) %>%
  mutate(shift_Yr = ifelse(Annual_Delta_18_19 < -sh | Annual_Delta_18_19 > sh, "2018/2019", ifelse(Annual_Delta_19_20 < -sh | Annual_Delta_19_20 > sh, "2019/2020", ""))) %>%
  mutate(Shift_From = ifelse(Annual_Delta_18_19 < -sh | Annual_Delta_19_20 < -sh, paste(Product), "")) %>%
  mutate(Shift_To = ifelse(Annual_Delta_18_19 > sh | Annual_Delta_19_20 > sh, paste(Product), "")) %>%
  filter(agg_18 >= minimum | agg_19 >= minimum | agg_20 >= minimum)
```

My Final results currently appear as the following, but I would like to see it all aggregated at the customer level (i.e. one row per customer) with shift identified at the monthly level, not annual:

[image]

**Final Comment:**
Any advice, packages, functions etc. that you can provide to help improve my current program is greatly appreciated. The sample data set is small, but ideally it would accommodate rather large data sets.

Comment: See the answer below.  If you want an additional column of sales of current product before next change, that can be catered too also.  However, please made it clear that whether you want a sum of sales of that product when it was main product only or a total cumulative sum irrespective of the fact that it was main or secondary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your expected output is not very clear, I think you want something like this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(1:3), names_to = "Month", values_to = "Sales") %>%
  mutate(Month = as.Date(paste0("01_", Month), "%d_%b_%y")) %>%
  group_by(Customer, Customer.ID, Month) %>%
  arrange(Customer, Month, Product) %>%
  mutate(Main = case_when(Sales == 0 ~ "nil",
                          Sales == max(Sales) ~ "main", 
                          TRUE ~ "secondary")) %>%
  group_by(Customer, Customer.ID, Product) %>%
  mutate(cumSales = cumsum(Sales)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(Main == "main") %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  mutate(shift = ifelse(Product == lag(Product, default = first(Product)), 0, 1),
         shifted_from = ifelse(shift == 1, lag(Product), NA),
         prev_prod_sales = ifelse(shift ==1, lag(cumSales), NA),
         shift_month = as.yearmon(Month, "%b %Y")) %>%
  filter(shift == 1) %>%
  select(Customer, Customer.ID, shifted_from, shifted_to = Product, shift_month, prev_prod_sales)

# A tibble: 20 x 6
# Groups:   Customer [7]
   Customer   Customer.ID shifted_from shifted_to shift_month prev_prod_sales
   <chr>      <chr>       <chr>        <chr>      <yearmon>             <int>
 1 Customer A 1A          Product Z    Product Y  Feb 2019                186
 2 Customer A 1A          Product Y    Product X  May 2020                207
 3 Customer B 2B          Product Y    Product X  Dec 2019                327
 4 Customer D 4D          Product X    Product U  Feb 2019                186
 5 Customer D 4D          Product U    Product Y  Mar 2019                 24
 6 Customer D 4D          Product Y    Product U  Jul 2019                 24
 7 Customer D 4D          Product U    Product Y  Jan 2020                137
 8 Customer D 4D          Product Y    Product U  Mar 2020                 36
 9 Customer D 4D          Product U    Product M  May 2020                207
10 Customer E 5E          Product Z    Product X  Aug 2018                 55
11 Customer E 5E          Product X    Product Z  Dec 2018                 12
12 Customer G 7G          Product Z    Product Y  Feb 2019                186
13 Customer G 7G          Product Y    Product Z  Feb 2020                149
14 Customer G 7G          Product Z    Product Y  Mar 2020                192
15 Customer G 7G          Product Y    Product X  May 2020                219
16 Customer I 9I          Product Y    Product X  Feb 2019                 17
17 Customer K 10K         Product U    Product M  Feb 2019                186
18 Customer K 10K         Product M    Product U  Feb 2020                149
19 Customer K 10K         Product U    Product M  Mar 2020                192
20 Customer K 10K         Product M    Product X  May 2020                219
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful and I apologize for the unclear description of the intended output. To answer the question in the above comment, I believe it would make most sense to only use the total of the sales when it is the main product. In addition to that though, is it also possible to flag "potential shift" (maybe as 2) if the % of sales for a new product is increasing over multiple periods but may not have enough in sales to be considered the main product?

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand yet.  Can you please calculate the desired output for a few rows manually and include that in your question so that I can figure that out